# How to find out when a stock started to trade on a US stock exchange?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, nasdaq

I see the initial date of AKTX is in Jun 07, 2013 on tradingview.

https://www.tradingview.com/chart/d0ZFlHyB/?symbol=NASDAQ%3AAKTX

But barchart shows Dec 2012 as the earliest date.

https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/AKTX/overview

I want to figure out the exact date this stock started to trade on NASDAQ. Could anybody show me how to do it from official document/database (e.g., via SEC filings)?

http://investor.akaritx.com/financial-information/sec-filings

Comment: You can look for S-1 for that security

Comment: This is a non-US company. Did you mean F-1? http://investor.akaritx.com/static-files/37d7963a-89d1-44c2-931f-7d8a12606cd8 . Where in this doc does it say the first trading day?

Comment: Under "Approximate date of commencement of proposed sale to the public"

Comment: But I don't see a specific date. So this doc does not have a specific date? Is there an alternative source that has the specific date?